# Заполнение БД SQLite при её создании

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Пытаюсь заполнить БД, во время создания, но не происходит ничего - нет ни сообщений об ошибках, нет внесения данных.  В чем ошибка у меня?

Первый вариант, через список arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="question">
 <item>Первый</item>
 <item>Второй</item>
 <item>Третий</item>
 <item>Еще один</item>
</string-array>
```

Класс самой БД:

```
private final Context fContext;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestLiriri";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "questions";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_QUEST = "quest";

    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();;
    String valueQuest;
    public String getValueQuest() {
        return valueQuest;
    }
    public void setValueQuest(String valueQuest) {
        this.valueQuest = valueQuest;
    }
    
    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        fContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_QUEST + " text" + ");");
        Resources res = fContext.getResources();
        String[] cattable_records = res.getStringArray(R.array.question);
        // проходим через массив и вставляем записи в таблицу
        int length = cattable_records.length;
        for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
            contentValues.put("title", cattable_records[i]);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
    }
```

И вариант, второй, прямое внесение строки в таблицу:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestLiriri";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "questions";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_QUEST = "quest";

    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String valueQuest;


    public String getValueQuest() {
        return valueQuest;
    }
    public void setValueQuest(String valueQuest) {
        this.valueQuest = valueQuest;
    }

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_QUEST + " text" + ");");
        WriteDB("Почему это не работает?");
    }

    public void WriteDB(String quest){
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        contentValues.put(KEY_QUEST, quest);
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
```

Comment: Вероятно поможет: integer primary key **autoincrement**. Для вставки строки нужны данные для всех колонок, либо колонки должны иметь дефолтные значения. Для первичного ключа это может быть автоинкремент.

Comment: integer primary key autoincrement - тоже не помогает и я не понимаю почему.  Для колонок не совсем понимаю, я же добавляю для них данные.

Comment: Не помогает скорее всего потому что база уже создана и `onCreate` больше не вызывается - нужно удалить базу с устройства (в настройках Андроида удалить данные приложения) и пробовать на чистую. Когда приложение уже опубликовано и вы его обновляете - такие трюки не приемлимы - поэтому вместо сноса базы можете заодно потренироваться сделать апгрейд. Повысить `DATABASE_VERSION` и реализовать `onUpgrade`, в котором сделать `drop` существующей таблицы и вызвать `onCreate`, который создаст уже правильную таблицу